# The fastest way to trim string in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to trim paths in million strings like this:

```
C:\workspace\my_projects\my_app\src\my_component\my_file.cpp
```

to

```
src\my_component\my_file.cpp
```

I.e. remove absolute part of the path, what is the fastest way to do that?

My try using regex:

```
Regex.Replace(path,  @"(.*?)\src", ""),
```

Comment: Have you _ever_ use `Trim` method of string class? Is it not enough fast? Did you ever measure them?

Comment: If you know the length ahead of time, I wonder if manipulating the underlying array wouldn't be faster

Comment: I think youre doing it right. Are you sure the replacement takes too long, and not reading the source strings into memory?

Comment: Why is trim speed an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't go with regex for this, use the plain old method.

If the path prefix is always the same:

```
const string partToRemove = @"C:\workspace\my_projects\my_app\";

if (path.StartsWith(partToRemove, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    path = path.Substring(partToRemove.Length);
```

If the prefix is variable, you can get the last index of `\src\`:

```
var startIndex = path.LastIndexOf(@"\src\", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (startIndex >= 0)
    path = path.Substring(startIndex + 1);
```

Comment: I disagree, the Regex is good, because it will function even with other pathes, with capitalized pathes, etc. Your solution anticipates that the input is sane. EVER SANITIZE YOUR INPUT.

Comment: @BeowulfOF I guess I've misunderstood the requirement then, I'll update the answer

Comment: `path.IndexOf(@"\src\", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);` ignores case so it should work fine. He also checks that the result is >= 0

Comment: I changed `IndexOf` to `LastIndexOf`. It seems safer in case the path prefix could be supplied by the user and have another `src` directory in it.

Answer (score 2):

define the regex with a new and reuse it
there is a (significant) cost to creating the regex

```
string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much   " + 
                     "whitespace.";
string pattern = "\\s+";
string replacement = " ";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Comment: OP mentioned trim, but seems he really needs a relative path maker

Answer (score 0):

Cant think any faster than this

```
path.Substring(33);
```

What is before `src` is constant. and it starts from index 33.

```
C:\workspace\my_projects\my_app\src\my_component\my_file.cpp
                                    ^
```

How ever if its not always constant. you can find it once. and do the rest inside loop.

```
int startInd = path.IndexOf(@"\src\") + 1;

// Do this inside loop. 1 million times
path.Substring(startInd);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your files will all end in "src/filename.ext" you could use the [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the .NET framework for it and get around all caveats you could have with pathes and filenames:

```
result = "src\" + Path.GetFileName(path);
```

So you should first double-check that the conversion is the thing that takes to long.

Comment: @lucas youre absolutly right. The last time I worked with C# I had to illegally download .NET sourcecode or use that famous tool that "decompiled" .NET classes.

Comment: Yeah I remember, this was the stone age of .NET :)

Comment: Thank you @lucas for making me feel old!

Comment: Stone age of a relatively young technology is still young, and heh, I remember this too ;)

Comment: Question @lucas how was that tool called? And how is it called today? I noticed that it had changed the name...

Comment: It was .NET Reflector. There was much drama involved with it, since Red Gate bought it, promised it will stay a freeware forever, and some time later made it into a paid software. Many other such tools emerged following the lack of a free Reflector. ILSpy, JustDecompile, dotPeek etc. Today I'd recommend dotPeek - it's better than Reflector, and it can display the original source code when available. And it feels just natural if you're used to ReSharper (BTW, if you're using R#, you get the decompiler integrated into VS directly).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need speed here, but if you *always* get the full path, you could do a simple `.Substring()`

```
var path = @"C:\workspace\my_projects\my_app\src\my_component\my_file.cpp";
Console.WriteLine(path.Substring(32));
```

However, I think you should sanitize your input first; in this case, the `Uri` class could do the parsing step:

```
var root = @"C:\workspace\my_projects\my_app\";
var path = @"C:\workspace\my_projects\my_app\src\my_component\my_file.cpp";
var relative = new Uri(root).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(path));
Console.WriteLine(relative.OriginalString.Replace("/", "\\"));
```

Notice here the `Uri` will change the `\` with a `/`: that's the `.Replace` reason.